# How can one discard individual changes in a file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, you can rollback all the changes to a file:

[image]

But is it possible if you have multiple changes in a file on multiple line numbers, to rollback only one of them, as one can in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 83):

**Update:** in the October 2017 release, ["inline change review" was introduced](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_inline-change-review), where you can easily discard a particular change in the same way as you would in IntelliJ-based IDEs:

[image]

---

Previously, this was only possible with the `Open Changes` UI (located in the upper right of editors [image]). Alternatively, you can run the `Git: Open Changes` command.

In that view, the `More` button ([image]) offers several options for operating on individual lines, among them `Revert Selected Ranges`.

[image]

Comment: No way to do this on an entire file without having to select anything?

Comment: In the meantime, the "inline change review" feature was added (updated my answer). Or are you asking how to discard _all_ changes in a file?

Comment: @Neeko see the back arrow in the question to the right of the file name? Click that.

Answer (score 21):

There is `Revert Selected Changes`. Either hit `Ctrl+Shift+P` on the diff viewer to revert selected or simply use `Ctrl+K,R`

[image]

Comment: Nice! I just select all text CMD/Ctrl + A and then do this to revert the file.